# How to rename a database in Spanner

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-spanner

How can I rename a database instance in Spanner?

I've tried:

- Google Cloud Platform console
- Spanner API

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, it is not possible to change the name of a database after you have created it. The documentation can be found here: https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/data-definition-language#database_statements

And it is clear when it comes to renaming a database:

> Cannot be changed after you create it.

Comment: I just realized that your questions could be interpreted in two ways. In case you want to rename a Google Cloud Spanner Instance (not Database), then it is possible: https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/create-manage-instances#editing_an_instance

Comment: Thanks! you interpreted correctly in the first place.